# Javascript `onerror` is not getting fired

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, onerror

Please have a look at the code below:

```
function longSentenceSpeak(text)
    {

        var url = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+finalString;
        var url2 = "http://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=sp&q="+finalString;

        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

        var source = document.getElementById('source');
        source.src=url;

        audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
        audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away

    audio.onerror = function()
    {
        var url2 = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q="+text;

        var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

        var source = document.getElementById('source');
        source.src = url2;

        audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
        audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away
    };
    }
```

Below is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="scripts/TTS.js"></script>
        <script>
           function longText()
           {
               longSentenceSpeak("hello world ");
           }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio id="audio">
            <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>

        <div><button onclick="longText()">Click me</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

However this gives this error, even though it should handle it:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (12:49:15:455 | error, network)
>         at http‍://www.translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=hello

What I want to do is, if this error occurred, I want to use `var url2` instead of `var url` in `function longSentenceSpeak(text)`. How can I do this?

Comment: try to wrap first call in `try` block, and call second function in `case` block

Comment: @KirillPisarev: I tried it too.

Comment: ok, mb `onstalled` handler? The stalled event occurs when the browser is trying to get media data, but data is not available.

Comment: @KirillPisarev: how to use it?

Comment: just change `onerror` to `onstalled`

Comment: @KirillPisarev: didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The `error` event doesn't bubble and in this case, it will fire on the <source> elements.
You thus need to listen to it from there:

```js
function longText() {

  var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

  var source = document.getElementById('source');
  source.src = '/foo.bar';
  audio.load(); //call this to just preload the audio without playing
  audio.play(); //call this to play the song right away

  source.onerror = function() {
   console.log('handling error event');
  };
  
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio">
  <source id="source" src="" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>

<div><button onclick="longText()">Click me</button></div>
```